# "list_editable" doesn't work in admin changelist view, using custom get_queryset() method

Tags: django, django-admin

I use custom abstract model with manager throughout my project.

```
class BaseQueryset(models.QuerySet):

   pass


class BaseManager(models.Manager):
   queryset_class = BaseQueryset

    def get_queryset(self, exclude_no_published=True):
        """ exclude all objects with is_published=False by default """
        q = self.queryset_class(self.model)
        if exclude_no_published:
            q = q.exclude(is_published=False)
        return q

    def all_objects(self):
        """ allows geting all objects in admin """
        return self.get_queryset(exclude_no_published=False)


class BaseAbstractModel(models.Model):

    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = BaseManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

All models inherit from this abstract model and I need a way to represent all objects in admin. So I wrote my own mixin for admin classes with `get_queryset` method

```
class AdminFullQuerysetMixin(object):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
    """
    Allows showing all objects despite on is_public=False
    """
        qs = self.model.objects.all_objects()
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
```

There is my typical admin class:

```
@admin.register(SomeModel)
class SomeModelAdmin(AdminFullQuerysetMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name', 'slug', 'is_published')
    list_filter = ('is_published',)
    list_editable = ('is_published',)
```

All works fine, I can see all objects in admin whether with `is_published` False or True. But such attributes like `list_filter` or `list_editable` don't work, when I use it in admin objects list page. There is no exception provided, just text at the top of the list: "Please correct the error below".
What methods except `get_queryset` should I override for solving my problem?

Comment: Please add the code for your admin class

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues Question updated, but there is no such logic in admin. all problems with `get_queryset` in my mixin, without that mixin all works fine but I can't see objects with `is_published=False`, because Django use my custom queryset

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong, but an alternative approach would be to have a custom queryset in your manager (`.published()`) and use that wherever needed, leaving Admin to use `.all()`. With that you don't need AdminFullQuerysetMixin nor `all_objects()`

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues you right but in that case I will need to call that `published()` everywhere instead of one place in admin, because by default I don't need items with `is_published=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) :

> if you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager
>   Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model)
>   has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a
>   class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (...) will
>   use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a result, **it’s a
>   good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to
>   avoid a situation where overriding get_queryset() results in an
>   inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with**.

I strongly suspect you fell upon one of those cases...

The solution would then be to change your model to:

```
class BaseAbstractModel(models.Model):

    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # this one will be the default manager
    all_objects = models.Manager()

    # and this one will be known as 'objects' 
    objects = BaseManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then you can remove your AdminFullQuerysetMixin (or rewrite it's `get_queryset()` method to use `self.model._default_manager` instead)

NB : I may of course be wrong and the problem be totally unrelated ;)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but my manager work as I expect. Objects with `is_published=False` should not be viewed in any part of a project except admin, for example I don't want to show objects with `False` flag in my DRF serializers, but I need an opportunity to change their state in admin. I  decided this approach will be more DRY than write two separate managers. I hope I will find solution in a `changelist_view` method, I think problem is here.

Comment: Your manager may work as you expect, but it obviously doesn't work as (parts of) Django expect - and I fail to see how using two managers would make you code less DRY than using your approach. But well, your call ;)

Comment: I thought  by mark it with False is similar to delete an instance, but it always possible to give it back in admin. In that case I'll need to call `all_objects` only in admin and in other parts of a project all instances will be hidden. Your approach is great, I will try it tomorrow. Depends on you experience in Django sure you know how build it better then me, I just afraid about fact that Django will call default  `all_objects` manager in other parts of my project when I don't need it.

Comment: I implemented your solution in my project. indeed it is clear and simple, thank you sir